# IDA, how to show ascii comment on immediate values?

Tags: ida

Today I used IDA on a owned compiled software.
I notice that IDA show me comment (ascii char) on immediates values as on this screenshoot below :
[image]

This is the first time I saw it automaticaly. What is the option the enable it ? Most of the time I must add ascii value comment manually...

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable "auto comments" https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1369.shtml

BTW you can write your own auto-commenting scripts like https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/idc/autocomment.shtml

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, autocomments show a short description of the instruction, not ascii characters on immediate values as OP requested.

Comment: Yes ! Option/General/ check Auto Comments

Comment: This is available in the education version not in the free one!